# How to Auto Login using BOX API ?

Tags: api, box-api

Hi StackOverflow Community!

I am working at BOX API . Everything is fine,but I want to change the Authentication behavior.

Authentication process first go to box website for ACCOUNT HOLDER Authentication. Is it possible to auto Authenticate using username/password and users view ACCOUNT HOLDER files directly?

I am looking forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640928/get-non-expiring-access-token-from-box-or-get-access-token-from-box-by-passing-u) with a solution involving renewing bearer and access tokens. Only restriction is that the renewal needs to occur at least once every 14 days. I hope this is a workable solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this isn't possible. The Box API uses OAuth 2.0 authentication, which explicitly requires you to redirect the user to the Box website so that they can "allow" access to their account. See http://developers.box.com/oauth/

Answer (score 0):

Which SDK are you using iOS, Windows, Ruby, other? It is possible to auto-login basically it would involve having the user configure their username and password somewhere. Then if you take those stored values and using javascript calls you can input the username and password into the appropriate fields and then submit the form. Depending on the api you'll be presented with a different login screen.

Disclaimer Box changes their login screen frequently and seems really buggy so I wouldn't recommend this route but if you want to do it any way the javascript will look something like:

```
var username = "user1";
var password = "superSecretPassword";

document.getElementById('login').value = 'username';
document.getElementById('password').value = 'password';
document.forms[0].submit();
```