# Box API Automatic Login for Authentication

Tags: api, box-api

This question was previously asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878683/how-to-auto-login-using-box-api) but the OP never responded to the comment left and therefore it is left unanswered. I'm looking to sign into a specific Box account via API and am hoping there's a way to automatically set the login and password instead of asking users for theirs. I'm coding my app in PHP and so far I'm using the basic OAuth2 process that asks the user to login (/auth/ticket&api_key). So far the only suggestions I've found requires saving files to local storage but that's not an option as I need my app users to do as little work as possible to get in. I just need to tweak this authentication process. Any suggestions??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this is the answer i got from Box API technical support:

> Unfortunately, there's no way to do this at this point. You do have to go through the web based login to authenticate, however once you authenticate the first time, you can automate the refresh token so you won't have to do it again. I apologize for that and just let me know if you have anymore questions about this.